# How to determine if TV is on by looking at yellow RCA monitor signal?

Tags: microcontroller, ntsc

I have a U.S./NTSC LCD HDTV that has a yellow RCA monitor jack on the back.  Would it be possible to monitor this connector on an analog input of a microcontroller to determine when the TV is on or off?

Unfortunately, I don't have scope that will let me look at the signal from the RCA jack.  I think my microcontroller's analog port typically measures from 0 to 5V.  Would I need a scaling circuit, resistor, diode, or something other than just hooking a wire directly to the analog input?  (Yes, I'm fairly inexperienced on the hardware side, thanks!)

What danger do I pose to the TV?

Comment: personally i would just use a power meter on the mains wire that provides some sort of way to see the current being drawn (analog or digital out).  I would bet that the monitor out RCA would only be active when standard def content is playing, as HD content wouldn't work on that type of connection, perhaps its down converting all the time but i doubt it, especially for hdmi inputs, thats a lot of processing work for the tv to be just randomly doing all the time.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll answer your question about danger to your TV: As long as you connect only high impedance test leads, you pose very little danger to your TV or anything else you want to measure.  This kind of input can be found on a DMM, an oscilloscope, or an analog input pin on an IC - as long as you do not exceed the maximum voltage of the part.  For the Arduino, this means you must be between -0.7 and 5.7V, to avoid turning on the diodes internal to your microcontroller.  As soon as you add discrete components between two digital transceivers, though, you risk a lot.
Also, make sure that your grounds are the same.  0V according to the TV might be much higher than 0V according to your earth-grounded PC.  Test this with a DMM beforehand, measuring between the shield of a USB cable to the shield of the RCA connector.  Put a 100k  resistor between the two shields.  Anything more than a couple volts on this measurement, and you've got trouble.

To answer your first question, though, the output of an NTSC signal in the US is 1V - source [this appnote](http://www.tek.com/Measurement/App_Notes/25_7049/eng/section2.pdf) from [this page about measuring video signals](http://www.tek.com/Measurement/App_Notes/25_7049/eng/) by Tektronix.   You'll see frequent references to units of [IRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRE_%28unit%29), which is a unit for measuring composite video signals that (Unlike voltage) is consistent between various formats and countries.  100 IRE is the difference between white and black.  An NTSC signal will never exceed 140 IRE, which is 1V, so 1 IRE is approximately 7mV *for your signal*.

If don't trust this random stranger on the Internet (backed by Tektronix, but how credible are they?),  you can connect your DMM instead of your Arduino, which should read the RMS (Root mean squared) value of what it supposes to be a DC input signal, and should be quite safe up to higher voltages than you want to get near enough to measure (600V?).  The AC amplitude likely won't work, as it's optimized for 60Hz household wiring, but check your manual.

Comment: Thanks.  most random strangers on the Internet don't know the stuff you do... :) So let's say I decide to hook it up to an Arduino (which isn't the specific MCU I had in mind, but I have one lying around), I would ground the shield (outside) of the RCA connector and hook the center pin to one of the analog ports?

Comment: So when I try to measure the difference in ground potential, as you described, I get about 100mV, but the meter floats around by about 10 - 20mV.  Even with the TV set off.  Why wouldn't it be more stable than that?

Comment: The shield *is* grounded already.  The important thing is to make sure that the ground on your Arduino and the ground on the shield are the same.  If you're using a battery or an isolated power supply (Like most wall warts), this does mean connecting the grounds. If you're using USB, which is earth grounded through your computer (unless, you're using a battery-powered laptop) you need to be sure that the ground on the USB is the same as the ground you find at that shield.  If you can reduce your ground loop, you'll get better readings (i.e., not uC GND pin -> USB -> PC -> Home wiring -> TV)

Comment: You're good - That tiny difference is because the two cables you're measuring are connected through the TV's PSU, then your home wiring, then the computer's PSU, then the USB connector on the motherboard, then the USB cable shield.  If you simply connect the two, the variation induced by this long wiring (aka ground loop) will be reduced, and you'll get better readings.

Comment: You always do need to be careful connecting grounds that are at different potentials together. For this situation, it is probably not necessary for them to be at the exact same level. Because of this can you put a small resistor in series when you connect the grounds together. This way, even if they are at separate voltages your resistor will be able to handle the difference.

Comment: If you wanted to go "All Out" you could make a preamp circuit that measured the difference between the tip and ring on your yellow monitor connector. I don't think you will need to worry about this though.

Answer (score 1):

Usually TVs are pretty good about protecting outputs like these. Manufactures know that people will accidentally short them and/or hook them up wrong. I would just be sure to not apply any voltage to the port.

In the simplest form, you will probably find that there is no voltage on the line when the TV is off and some voltage when the TV is on. If you have a DMM, you can check to see if you observe this. Check with the DMM on both the DC mode and AC mode.

Comment: So when I hook a DMM up to the center pin and surrounding shield of an RCA cable, voltage floats all over the place.  Is the shield supposed to be grounded?

Comment: For some specific numbers, I just tried this again.  TV off: 0.8mV, TV on: Jumps up to 2.7V and slowly trickles down.  Turning the set off again makes the meter jump, but eventually it just settles back to the value it was on before I turned it off, then the voltage continues to slowly trickle down.

Comment: .8mV is practically ground and should be treated as such for this application. The "trickling down" that you see is probably some stray capacitance, this means that if you put a resistor across the output (say 10k) it should bring the voltage down much quicker. Do you have your DMM set to AC or DC?

Comment: The meter is set to DC.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow RCA jack should output standard NTSC signals, if it is an Output.  The yellow RCA input should be a high-impedance input, so the level on that won't tell you much about the status of the TV.  On the output jack, NTSC voltage levels vary between 0V and 1.0V practically--some TVs vary on high-white output.  The easiest way would be to check for the line going low for 4.7uS or the horizontal sync pulse.  You could also check for the vertical syncs, but many TVs disagree on the standard for that too.  If the TV is on, the output for video should show 4.7uS h-sync pules, and then color-burst/blanking and then pixel data after that.  The problem with measuring it on a DC meter is the AC nature of the signal, and an AC meter will just average the entire signal.  You might be able to experiment with it a little bit.

Comment: "The yellow RCA input should be a high-impedance input." Incorrect, baseband video is impedance-matched at 75 ohms.